# EPPlus Object reference Error with saving file. Why is this happening?

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm creating a basic program that writes some data to excel. I'm pretty new to C#, and certainly new to EPPlus. I have had a very difficult time finding good documentation about this package, but nevertheless..

My code is as follows..

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

/* CHANGELOG
 * 11/26/2019
 * Added basic support for excel database using EPPlus library
 * 
 */



/* BUGS, FIXES, AND TODO
 * 
 * ******BUGS******
 * 
 * [] Fix loop to loop through each item in given array instead of specified length. Perhaps a foreach makes more sense?
 *
 *    
 *    
 * ******TODO******   
 * [x] Figure out best way to write information to a file (Excel?)
 * [] Create Duplicate Entry detector?
 * [] Possible to loop through args in visitor constructor?
 * [] Prefill information from membership info (Bar code on mem card?)   
 * [] Set tab index of all items   
 * [] Allow user to export database to excel w/ path of choosing.
 * [] 
 *    
 *    
 */


namespace Nonprofit_Attendance_App
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        //Declare Global Variables
        public static class Globals
        {

            public static string excelSheet = "";
            public static ExcelWorksheet wsSheet1;
            public static ExcelPackage ExcelPkg;
            public static string userIn;
            public static string[] alphabet = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
            public static int dataPosition;
        }


        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create new visitor object with form input
            Visitor Paal = new Visitor( vis_zip.Text, 
                vis_entrance_courtYard.Checked, 
                vis_entrance_frontDoor.Checked, 
                vis_reason_general.Checked, 
                vis_reason_meeting.Checked, 
                vis_reason_photography.Checked, 
                vis_reason_cafe.Checked, 
                vis_firstTime.Checked, 
                vis_returning.Checked, 
                vis_both.Checked, 
                vis_mem.Checked, 
                vis_mem_lastName.Text );

            //Loop through Visitor object to write data to console. DELETE EVENTUALLY

            foreach (var item in Paal.vis_data)
            {

            Console.WriteLine(item);

            }

            writeData(Paal.vis_data);



            //Clear form after submit 
            vis_zip.Text = string.Empty;
            vis_entrance_courtYard.Checked = false;
            vis_entrance_frontDoor.Checked = false;
            vis_reason_general.Checked = false;
            vis_reason_meeting.Checked = false;
            vis_reason_photography.Checked = false;
            vis_reason_cafe.Checked = false;
            vis_firstTime.Checked = false;
            vis_returning.Checked = false;
            vis_both.Checked = false;
            vis_mem.Checked = false;
            vis_mem_lastName.Text = string.Empty;

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        class Visitor
        { 
            public string[] vis_data = new string[12];
            public Visitor(string zipCode, bool entrance_courtYard, bool entrance_frontDoor, bool vis_reason_general, bool vis_reason_meeting, bool vis_reason_photo, bool vis_reason_cafe, bool vis_firstTime, bool vis_Returning, bool vis_both, bool vis_mem, string vis_mem_lastName)
            {
                //Write to Excel Sheet
                //FIX EMPTY ENTRIES
                vis_data[0] = zipCode;

                if (entrance_courtYard == true)
                {
                    vis_data[1] = "Courtyard";
                }
                else
                {
                    vis_data[1] = "Front Door";
                }

                if (vis_reason_general == true)
                {
                    vis_data[2] += "General Visit";
                }
                else if (vis_reason_meeting == true)
                {
                    vis_data[2] += "Meeting";
                }
                else if (vis_reason_cafe == true)
                {
                    vis_data[2] += "Cafe";
                }
                else if (vis_reason_photo == true)
                {
                    vis_data[2] += "Photography";
                }
                else
                {
                    vis_data[2] = "null";
                }

                if (vis_firstTime == true)
                {
                    vis_data[3] = "First Time";
                }
                else if (vis_Returning == true)
                {
                    vis_data[3] = "Returning";
                }
                else if (vis_both == true)
                {
                    vis_data[3] = "Both";
                }
                else
                {
                    vis_data[3] = "null";
                }


                if (vis_mem)
                {
                    vis_data[4] = vis_mem_lastName;
                }
                else
                {
                    vis_data[4] = "Not a member";
                }

                vis_data[5] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void vis_frontDoor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //Enable member last name when member checkbox is checked
        private void vis_mem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (vis_mem.Checked)
            {
                vis_mem_lastName.Enabled = true;
            } 
            else
            {
                vis_mem_lastName.Enabled = false;
            }

        }

        private void vis_mem_lastName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        //Generates Excel database
        public static void generateExcel()
        {
            //get user input for database name

            //Excel Sheet Generation
            Globals.ExcelPkg = new ExcelPackage();
            Globals.wsSheet1 = Globals.ExcelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            Globals.wsSheet1.Protection.IsProtected = false;
            Globals.wsSheet1.Protection.AllowSelectLockedCells = false;
            Globals.excelSheet = @"C:\Users\paalw\documents\database.xlsx";
            Globals.ExcelPkg.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\paalw\documents\database.xlsx"));

        }
        //TO FINISH
        public static void setHeaders()
        {

            using (ExcelRange Rng = Globals.wsSheet1.Cells)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {
                     Rng[Globals.alphabet[i] + 1].Value = i;
                }

            }

        }

        public void getDataPosition()
        {
            using (ExcelRange Rng = Globals.wsSheet1.Cells)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Rng["A" + i].Value) == false)
                    {
                        Globals.dataPosition = i;
                        Console.WriteLine(Globals.dataPosition);
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        public void writeData(string[] x)
        {

            using (ExcelRange Rng = Globals.wsSheet1.Cells)

            {
                int i = 0;
                int j = Globals.dataPosition;
                foreach (var item in x)
                {
                    Rng[Globals.alphabet[i] + j].Value = x[i];
                    i++;
                }
                Globals.dataPosition++;
            }

        }


        private void fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 

            if (File.Exists(Globals.excelSheet))
            {
                Globals.excelSheet = @"C:\Users\paalw\documents\database.xlsx";

                //NEED TO set FileLocation to existing Sheet
                MessageBox.Show("Connected to Databse");
                getDataPosition();
            }
            else
            {

                generateExcel();
                setHeaders();
                getDataPosition();

            }
        }

        private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Globals.ExcelPkg.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run Globals.ExcelPkg.Save();, regardless of where it exists in the program or when it is run, I keep getting an object reference error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I'm not very clear on why this is happening, because when I am running the generateExcel(); method it should be setting Globals.ExcelPkg to the current database thats being created. Its like whenever the application runs once it completely clears that variable. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated because I've been pulling my hair out over this for the last week now.

Comment: Please remove unused code blocks and comments so it is easy to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

The above code throws `System.NullReferenceException` with `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` at `using (ExcelRange Rng = Globals.wsSheet1.Cells)` in `writeData(string[] x)`

Because `wsSheet1` was declared in `Globals` class but not initialized. Also you have to call `setHeaders()` and `getDataPosition()` methods in `generateExcel()` before saving the excel file.

Simple example to generate excel using EPPlus:

```
public static void GenerateExcel(List<Users> users, string _path)
{
    using (ExcelPackage exPackage = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = exPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_path));
        ws.Cells.Style.Font.SetFromFont(new Font("Calibri", 10));
        ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

        ExcelRange aHeaderRange = ws.Cells["A1:E1"];
        aHeaderRange.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        aHeaderRange.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);
        short rNo = 1;
        ws.Cells[rNo, 1].Value = "Customer No";
        ws.Cells[rNo, 2].Value = "Name";
        ws.Cells[rNo, 3].Value = "DoB";
        ws.Cells[rNo, 4].Value = "Designation";
        ws.Cells[rNo, 5].Value = "Address";

        rNo = 2;
        foreach (var m in users)
        {
            ws.Cells[rNo, 1].Value = m.CustNo;
            ws.Cells[rNo, 2].Value = m.Name;
            ws.Cells[rNo, 3].Value = m.DoB;
            ws.Cells[rNo, 4].Value = m.Designation;
            ws.Cells[rNo, 5].Value = m.Address;
            rNo++;
        }

        FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(_path);
        exPackage.SaveAs(excelFile);
    }
}

public class Users
{
    public string CustNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DoB { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

** Here, users is list of users to store in excel file and _path is the location where to save the excel file.

Links to tutorials
https://riptutorial.com/epplus

https://itenium.be/blog/dotnet/create-xlsx-excel-with-epplus-csharp/